# Changing a piecewise function into a periodic function

Tags: plotting

I have:

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{x, 0 <= x < 1}, {2 - x, 1 <= x < 3}, {x - 4, 
    3 <= x < 4}}]
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 4}]
```

Which produces this plot:

[image]

I'm looking for a simple way to convert this into a periodic function so that this image repeats itself every 4 units, in either the positive or negative direction along the x-axis.

Anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
f1[y_] := f[Mod[y, 4]]
Plot[f1[x], {x, -8, 8}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Is that a Plot1 there instead of a Plot? And, after I changed it to a Plot, I got your plot, by mine had breaks in it. I can post it if you want.

Comment: @David Sorry, finger misplaced. You may get those blanks disappearing  by increasing the PlotPoints Option