# Weird output when plot piecewise continuous and periodic functions

Tags: plotting

I refer to this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/105959/changing-a-piecewise-function-into-a-periodic-function) and try to plot a piecewise continuous and periodic function. This periodic function is defined as following:

$$h(x)=|x|, x\in [-1,1] , ~h(x+2)=h(x)$$

$$f_n(x)=\frac{1}{2^n}h(2^n x),~~~~g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)$$

I want to plot $g(x)$. Here I only plot for the sum of first four terms, namely $g_3(x)=f_0(x)+f_1(x)+f_2(x)+f_3(x)$.

```
f[x_, n_] := 
 Piecewise[{{1/2^(n - 1) - x, 1/2^n <= x < 2/2^n}, {x, 0 <= x < 1/2^n}}]

g[y_, n_] := f[Mod[y, 1/2^(n - 1)], n]

Plot[Sum[g[x, k], {k, 0, 3}], {x, -1, 2}, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

But why I got those breaking spacing for those lines in the graph? (I use Mathematica 10.0)
[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior Mathematica version 13. Can you see if adding an explicit `PlotPoints` option improves the situation?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Yes, after I set PlotPoints->5000, there is no those gaps anymore, but this will make the running very slow to generate the plot. I don't understand why this happens...

Comment: Try `Plot[Sum[g[x, k], {k, 0, 3}] // PiecewiseExpand // Evaluate, {x, -1, 2}, AspectRatio -> 1/2]`

Comment: It doesn't work, still having those breaking spacings @BobHanlon

Comment: Try increasing `MaxRecursions` that should enable smaller values for `PlotPoints`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- It it recommended to use `Mod` to do with period functions.
- Since `h` defined from `-1` to `1`,it's period is equal to `2` and start from `-1`,so we use `Mod[x,2,-1]`.

```
Clear[h, f, g];
h[x_ /; -1 <= x <= 1] = Abs[x];
h[x_] := h[Mod[x, 2, -1]]
f[x_, n_] := h[2^n x]/2^n;
g[x_, n_] := Sum[f[x, k], {k, 0, n}]
Plot[g[x, 3], {x, -1, 2}]
Plot[g[x, 10], {x, -1, 2}]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you! This one works, and in your second line, what does "h[x_ /; " mean?

Comment: @MathFail `/;` is the function `Condition[]`

Comment: Thank you very much!